# SFTP to S3 distributed file copy using elastic map reduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

I have a requirement to copy files periodically from a server using SFTP to an AWS S3 bucket. At the moment I'm doing it through a cron job using Python's Paramiko module and AWS Boto. I was wondering if there is a way to do this more efficiently through AWS elastic mapreduce (EMR). The S3DistCp tool is great for copying data from S3 to S3 buckets using EMR however I haven't found anything for distributed file copy from SFTP to S3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `SFTP` capability natively available in Amazon Elastic Map Reduce (EMR).

Using EMR would add **significant overhead**, both in terms of complexity and time to process (eg having to have a cluster running and each job taking up to 30 seconds just to start). `S3DistCp` is indeed useful for parallel copying of many files, but would only be worthwhile if you have hundreds of files to copy.

You might consider managing the SFTP portion to retrieve files to a temporary location, but then calling out to the **[AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** to handle the file upload. That would remove some of the difficult bits (eg error checking, multi-part uploads) from your code.

To make full use of network bandwidth, you could use a tool such as [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to perform multiple simultaneous uploads:

```
ls * | parallel --no-notice -j100 aws s3 cp {1} s3://my-bucket/{1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts John. I experimented with using the AWS data pipeline to automate this task. Using the pipeline provides some benefits you mentioned including retries and notifications. The data pipeline probably uses multi-part data upload to the S3DataNode. This solution is probably ok for small to medium sets of files (a few hundred) that are not that large (in 10's of MB). For larger sets of files that are very large (GB) I wonder if using a pig/hive script might be a possibility in that situation.

Comment: EMR would be useful for a large quantity of files, since they are done in parallel from multiple nodes. If it is a small number of large files, there is less benefit. I've added an example of doing parallel uploads via the CLI.